# Mathematical background required for Lagrangian Field Theory?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, education, mathematics, variational-calculus

I want to start teaching myself Lagrangian Field Theory. I can do multivariable calc, tensor calc, Lagrangian mechanics, and some calculus of variations. Are there other math fields I should study before diving in to field theories? I’m hoping to work my way up to QFT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert on the field, but when I was in college I was taught many concepts in Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics that required group theory. It would be nice to have it on your maths background, apart from the ones you already have.